# Querying an array of JSONB fields in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

I have trouble figuring out how to query PostgreSQL JsonB datatype. I have a simple table with the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, answers JSONB)
```

All Json documents in the column "answers" are of the form:

```
[
{"R" : "aaa", "V" : 25},
{"R" : "aaa", "V" : 31}, 
{"R" : "bbb", "V" : 38}
...
]
```

There can be many elements in the list, but all elements will have a "R" and a "V" item.

I would like to retrieve a table using SQL, listing Ids, and a Json list of all the "V"s where "R" == "aaa" .

For the example above, I would get:

- Id for the record
- [25, 31]   -- the two "V" values where "R" == "aaa"

Any thoughts? Any help appreciated I have spent some time on the JSon paths examples available on the web, but haven't found something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a `jsonb`, `json`, or `int[]` array?

Comment: Jsonb/Json would be best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Postgresql 12+ only

Using jsonpath:

```
WITH data(id, json_arr) AS (
    VALUES (1, $$[
      { "R": "aaa", "V": 25 },
      { "R": "aaa", "V": 31 },
      { "R": "bbb", "V": 38 }
    ]$$::JSONB)
)
SELECT id,
       -- $[*]             : "inside the top level array"
       -- ? (@.R == "aaa") : "keep only when the "R" key's value is "aaa""
       -- .V               : "select the "V" key of those elements"
       jsonb_path_query_array(json_arr, '$[*] ? (@.R == "aaa").V')
FROM data
```

returns:

```
+--+----------------------+
|id|jsonb_path_query_array|
+--+----------------------+
|1 |[25, 31]              |
+--+----------------------+
```

---

Note: you can also use

```
jsonb_path_query_array(
    json_arr,
    '$[*] ? (@.R == $r_value).V',
    '{"r_value": "aaa"}'  -- pass the 'r_value' to the query above
)
```

Comment: only for ```postgresql-12```

Comment: @ИгорьТыра: True, though I assumed this was OK since the OP mentioned jsonpath in his question. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would expand the elements out, filter by `R`, and then reaggregate.  This results in an `int[]` array.

```
select m.id, array_agg((a.obj->>'V')::int) as vvals
  from mytable m
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(answers) as a(obj)
 where a.obj->>'R' = 'aaa';
```

Comment: The result should probably be a JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

all in pure JSONB:

```
SELECT id, jsonb_agg(ans->'V') FROM (
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(answers) AS ans
  FROM myTable
) zz
WHERE ans->'R' = '"aaa"'
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer, and very readable too. Marth's answer is a bit faster, with the constraint of PG12, so I picked it, but yours was very helpful too in pushing my understanding forward!